# PayPal SDK - Paying by Credit Card, means any Credit Card

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have just added Paypal SDK, installing products to be paid through credit card using Paypal SDK instead of paying through Paypal Redirect.

Does this mean if you pay by entering your credit card details using Paypal SDK, you still have too register the card with paypal, in order to pay by the card?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 major ways to do that.

First, let Paypal handle the processing. you need to save the card or reference, for payment management, such as refunds. or if it's recurring payments, updating the card. that way paypal returns an ID you can use later for management.

this is done by redirecting to paypal with payment creation (via Paypal UI).

Second, if you wish to have your own UI without redirect, you can use the API to send credit card details, but then you also need to save the card details somewhere. if you wish to self-manage the cards, then you have to become PCI-compliant, which is a major security concern (you can't just keep the numbers and cvv).

Or, you can use Paypal's "Vault" service via API to save the card, while inserting the card details in your UI, then you can use payment with the returned ID. you can use the ID for future management functions.

If you need more help, try using Paypal's support, or add more details on what API's you're using, etc...